# How to use bootstrap class in best_in_place gem rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am trying to give bootstrap class `form-control` in text field, but it didn't works.
Code:

```
 <% @user.each do |record| %>    
   <tr>
    <td>
      <%= best_in_place record, :name, :as => :input %> 
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= best_in_place record, :gender, :as => :select, collection: (MUser.pluck(:id, 
     :gender)), inner_class: 'form-control %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= best_in_place record, :dob, :as => :date, class: 'datepicker1 %>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

how can i give bootstrap class in best_in_place fields?

Comment: @Nitin Srivastava Sir, please check this one also.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out bootstrap classes based on input type. For example for `text` field we have `form-control` class while for `select` we have `custom-select` class.

Use these classes based on the field type. Here is code snippet which may help you.

```
<td>
  <%= best_in_place record, :name, as: :input, inner_class: 'form-control' %> 
</td>
<td>
  <%= best_in_place record, :gender, as: :select, collection: (MUser.pluck(:id, 
 :gender)), inner_class: 'custom-select' %>
</td>
```

[image]
[image]
Happy coding :)